# How to run more advanced proximity searches?

Tags: solr, full-text-search

Are there ways to run more advanced proximity searches on Solr? On various online full-text aggregators (like EBSCO, ProQuest, etc.), we often work with 'baskets' of search terms (both words - e.g. 'security' and phrases - e.g. 'soft power'). So our search query might be something like

- Our first basket - e.g. ((security OR "soft power" OR influence) NOT "social security")
- a proximity operator - e.g. within 5 words to the left or to the right of any of those first search terms
- and then the second or third or ... basket - e.g. (Russia* OR "post-Soviet")

Each of our baskets may contain tens of search terms.

Is something like this possible in Solr? If so - how? And if not, is there another, better option for an Apache server? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like the exact use case for the [Complex Phrase Query Parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser)?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks! But could you be a bit more precise? The documentation only gives a very simple example `{!surround} 3w(foo, bar)`. But so should our syntax be  something like `{!surround} 5w((security OR "soft power" OR influence) NOT "social security")),(Russia* OR "post-Soviet"))` ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the parser, so I recommend playing around with it with a document that you know should match - I don't have a good example around. If you add one to your question, it'd be easier to test myself.

Comment: The problem is that this is for an online full-text database with mostly newspaper articles that we subscribe to. So we only have access to the GUI, and that doesn't accept the `{!surround}` in the search query box. But we've contacted their developers about it. I was just hoping that somebody here would have be more familiar with the correct syntax for that parser...